# How can I generate Allure report files when working with Django and manage.py test runner?

Tags: python, django, allure

I have a Django project and I usually run the unit tests with the command:

```
manage.py test
```

I have installed `allure-pytest` but I don't know how to use it. The documentation is about using `pytest`, but I don't use `pytest` to run my tests.

Does anyone know how I should run my Django tests and make them generate allure report files, when I use the `manage.py test` command to run them?

Answer (score 1):

`allure-pytest` is deprecated. Try using [allure-python](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python)

[image]

- How to install :
  https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_installing_a_commandline
- How to run tests : https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_test_execution Report
- How to generate reports : https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_report_generation
- Documentation : https://docs.qameta.io/allure/

Reference : https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, `allure-python` is not on PyPi. I have tried to install it from Github, but didn't work. Also, the links that you are pointing me to, do not explain how to run the tests using `manage.py test` command line interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use django tests with allure, you need to install following packages:

```
allure-pytest
pytest-django
```

Create a **pytest.ini**:

```
# -- FILE: pytest.ini (or tox.ini)
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = test_settings
# -- recommended but optional:
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

Where `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` should point to your django settings.

After that you can just run pytest:

```
pytest --alluredir=allure_results
```

And run allure:

```
allure serve allure_results
```